# Synapse Analytics - Can't see the tables list in the dedicated sql pool - I can Query table & tables not showing in SSMS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

i have added few tables via SSMS on Azure Synapse Data warehouse. i can see tables list on Azure as well i can query in SSMS but SSMS "Tables" not showing tables list

[image: Azure Tables List]

You can see SSMS is not showing tables list, i have refresh it & can query to tables which i created, But SSMS is not  showing tables list, where Azure showing tables list

[image: SSMS Screen shot - you can tables list not showing after refresh as well]

Answer (score 0):

​Please verify on the below scenarios:

1. Check if there is a DENY permission on VIEW ANY DATABASE
2. See when connecting using SSMS, if you set the database to connect to explicitly. On connect, go to Options, then check the database you're connecting to. If you're using multiple users to connect to that server, you end up being forced to connect to a single database instead of < default >
3. SSMS does not automatically update the database list when new databases are added. You need to refresh the view manually.

   In Object Explorer, highlight the Databases node. Hit F5 to refresh. The list of databases should refresh and your new database should appear.

   Another method would be to disconnect SSMS from the server and reconnect.